# How to fix this Wordpress Fatal error?

Tags: php, wordpress

This error execute from functions.php

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare new_excerpt_more() (previously declared
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\odishaddugkyalumnai\wp-content\themes\odishaddugkyalumnai\functions.php:626)
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\odishaddugkyalumnai\wp-content\themes\odishaddugkyalumnai\functions.php
>   on line 649

Answer (score 2):

open this file

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\odishaddugkyalumnai\wp-content\themes\odishaddugkyalumnai\functions.php
```

and serch for "new_excerpt_more" function and delete it.